# How to get binding Active Directory username in OSX

Tags: objective-c, macos

I have binding a MAC account by 'Users & Group'->Login Options. But when search user name in mac.I only get local user name and I can't found it on Active Directory users.
Who can tell me why I can't get the name 'user1' in AD user list?

for example:
I binding user 'user1' to Active Directory by AD count 'Admin1'.
I want to get username 'Admin1'.but I can not found 'Admin1' in Local or network Manage user list.

Anybody can help me for this problem?

reference:
[(Objective-c/Mac OSX) How to distinguish managed AD users (AD user create mobile card) from local users on Mac OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24910129/objective-c-mac-osx-how-to-distinguish-managed-ad-users-ad-user-create-mobile)

Answer (score 0):

I found out ,if you bind a mac to AD by administrator,you can get all AD account and login in any AD account.administrator account is not import,it only use in binding.
after bind,you can get local user list and network managed user list by iOS coding.the network managed user list is what we need: AD user list.